# SQLcl fails to run scripts even with Oracle JDK 8 installed

Tags: java, oracle, sqlcl

I have Oracle JDK 8 installed and SQLcl of version 21.3. I want to run simple js script but SQLcl cannot find js engine.

I run SQLcl from PowerShell under Windows 10:

```
PS C:\run_scripts_sqlcl> sql /nolog
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Duser.language=en


SQLcl: Release 21.3 Production on Thu Nov 04 00:32:25 2021

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

SQL> show java
Java Detail
-----------
java.home= C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_311\jre
java.vendor= Oracle Corporation
java.vendor.url= http://java.oracle.com/
java.version= 1.8.0_311
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
os.arch= amd64
os.name= Windows 10
os.version= 10.0
path.separator= ;
file.separator= \
line.separator=

user.dir= C:\run_scripts_sqlcl
user.home= C:\Users\user
user.name= Roman.Shiryaev
user.language= en
user.region= null
file.encoding= Cp1251
Used memory: 57.2MB
Max available memory: 1,820.5MB
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL_HOME=null
Classpath

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
null
SQL> script
  2  print('hi');
  3* /
js language engine not found
Please add js language engine to the classpath
SQL>
```

Seems like I haven't configured something properly but I can't find any information about configuring SQLcl for running scripts. I've tried to set env variable CLASSPATH to %JDK_HOME%/bin but it didn't help. Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm talking about running Nashorn scripts that are supported by SQLcl tool.

Comment: Problem is the Java home java.home= C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_311\jre ... That jre is screwing things up

Comment: You need a full JDK for scripting, not just the JRE.

Answer (score 0):

After contacting Oracle Support they advised the following:

- Remove all existing Javas, especially installed via installer
- Download Java 11 JDK
- Place it in a folder `jdk` on the same level as `sqlcl`
- Create `jre` folder inside of `jdk` and copy contents of `jdk` folder into `jre` one

After such action it finally managed to run scripts. Seems like very confusing for resolving Java path under Windows as it doesn't resolve it from PATH variable or JAVA_HOME.